# Capping & Calculating FPS in SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, frame-rate, game-development

I have written this code to cap the SDL game to 60 fps, is this the correct way of implementing an fps count?

```
int fps=60;
int desiredDelta=1000/fps;  //desired time b/w frames


while (gameRunning)
{

    int starttick=SDL_GetTicks();

    // Get our controls and events
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            gameRunning = false;
    }
    window.Clear();

    for(Entity& e: entities)
    {
        window.Render(e);
    }

    window.Display();

    int delta=SDL_GetTicks()-starttick;     //actual time b/w frames

    int avgFPS=1000/(desiredDelta-delta);  //calculating FPS HERE

    if(delta<desiredDelta)
    {
        SDL_Delay(desiredDelta-delta);
    }
  
    std::cout<<avgFPS<<std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but would it happen that you try to limit you renders to screen refresh rate? Because if this is your actual intent, you could just enable VSync and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, I added the vsync flag but I thought you still need to manually cap the fps right? I was watching codergopheers tutorials and he adds a timestep , I assumed it was just like a frame rate cap

Comment: If you have vsync enabled, then the actual presentation of the result by your framework should block as appropriate (I don't know SDL well enough to point you to the correct documentation alas). You still need to keep track of time, so you know how much time elapsed and can compute world updates as appropriate (so your game is not 66% faster on 100Hz monitor than on a 60Hz monitor).

Answer (score 4):

In games there are usually two "framerates" to worry about: the framerate of the display and the framerate of your game physics. Ideally, you *draw* at the native framerate of the display. To do this, ensure you pass the `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` flag to [`SDL_CreateRenderer()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer).

For the physics of your game, you can either measure the time between two rendered frames, and use that as your physics time step, so that you basically match the display framerate. The advantage is that your rates are naturally synced, but the disadvantage is that the physics of the game might suffer from accuracy problems, especially during times when rendering takes so long that the display framerate drops to low values.

Alternatively, you use a fixed framerate for your physics. However, if you do the latter then you have to some how deal with the two framerates not being in sync, but this is not solved by adding `SDL_Delay()`s. The usual approach is to have the rendering thread interpolate animations based on physics as necessary.

A more practical issue in your code is that `SDL_GetTicks()` gives you the time in milliseconds. That is not very accurate; if your display runs at 60 fps, then one frame takes 16.66666... milliseconds. Your calculation will have an error of up to 1 ms, which is 6.25% of the length of one frame. Depending on the type of game, this can actually be noticable!